# Selenium - Key press events not working when automation scripts are run using Jenkins service

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation, keypress

Facing a problem when running my scripts in Jenkins , noticed that the key press events for e.g

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP);
```

Are not working when scripts are executed using Jenkins service.This works fine on my local.

Did any one came across this kind of problem when executing scripts using jenkins service on window machine ?

Application running on Chrome browser.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Use AutoIT for the operations instead of Robot class , Robot classes are highly unstable .

Comment: @cruisepandey Thanks for your response, Using JsExecutor instead of robot now for scroll up event and it is working fine.
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)", "");

Comment: Great ! I thought you were dealing with upload scenario where you have to interact with windows based pop up , that's why I told you to use AutoIT , for scrollup and scrollDown you can go ahead with JavaScriptExecutor.

Comment: @cruisepandey Thank you for your input. Good day

Comment: Good day !! @mk_